# plot function against composite variable

Tags: plotting

How can one plot $f(x,y)$ as a pseudo-univariate function of $x/y$ (or some other composition of these variables) over the domain $a<\frac{x}{y}<b$. `Plot[f,{x/y,a,b}]` produces the following error

```
Plot::write: Tag Times in x/y is Protected. >>
```

The alternative is to redefine the function in terms of a single variable (i.e., replace all occurrences of `x/y` with a new variable `z`); however, I wish to avoid tedious manual redefinition if possible.

**Edit:** As a simple example, consider the function

$$f(x,y) = \frac{y^2}{x^2}\times\exp(x/y)+5\frac{x}{y}.$$

This function could be redefined as

$$g(z)=\frac{\exp(z)}{z^2}+5z$$

where $z\equiv x/y$.

One could redefine their function $f(x,y)$ as $g(z)$, but it would be more convenient if one could simply plot $f(x,y)$ against $x/y$ as a pseudo-univariate function.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?  Do `f[1,1]` and `f[2,2]` give the same answer?

Comment: Hi @BrettChampion. Yes, f[1,1] and f[2,2] give the same answer. I have edited my post to include a concrete example.

Comment: This is an ill-posed problem. There are arbitrarily many ways to write a real number as a fraction of two others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses `Rationalize` to turn a real number into a rational number, and extracts the numerator and denominator to be used when evaluating `f[x,y]`.

```
f[x_, y_] := y^2/x^2 Exp[x/y] + 5 x/y

g[xy_?NumericQ] := 
    With[{r = Rationalize[xy, 0]}, 
        f[Numerator[r], Denominator[r]]
        ]

Plot[g[xy], {xy, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

A few notes:

- the definition of `g` doesn't need to know what `f` is.
- I used `Rationalize[x, 0]` to make sure the result is rational, avoiding cases like  `Rationalize[0.123423789]` returning `0.123423789`.
- I used `_?NumericQ` to make sure `g` is only defined for numbers, since `Rationalize[x,0]` will return `x`, which I want to avoid.

Comment: That's impressive. I understand your approach as you described it, but I don't follow all the syntax (I am still new to Mathematica). Could you briefly explain it?

Comment: @user001 I added a bit, let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks. That is very clever. Is there a way to generalize it? Suppose, one wanted to use as an argument $x^2 + y$, $xy$, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Jens's comment that the problem is ill posed.  But you can still brute force it numerically by abusing `ParametricPlot`:

```
ParametricPlot[{x/y, (5 x)/y + (E^(x/y) y^2)/x^2}, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}, 
  Mesh -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is ugly but convenient.  When the function can't be expressed in terms of the composite variable you chose, this will give a surface instead of a line (thus it gives you instant verification as well).

---

Alternatively you can try to [do the variable replacement symbolically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2321/12):

```
Solve[Eliminate[{f == (5 x)/y + (E^(x/y) y^2)/x^2, z == x/y}, {x, y}], f]

(* ==> {{f -> (E^z + 5 z^3)/z^2}} *)
```